# i want Upload video to vimeo from api

Tags: php, file-upload

how selcet path to a video on the file system php

i want Upload video to vimeo from api

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/videos/upload

how selcet path to a video on the file system php

$file_name = "{path_to_a_video_on_the_file_system}";????

```
<body>
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
$client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token);
if (isset($_POST['saveUniv'])) {

    $file_name = realpath($_FILES['my_field_add']['tmp_name']);
    $uri = $client->upload($file_name, array(
        "name" => "title_file",
        "description" => "description file"
    ));
   $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
    if ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'complete') {
        print 'Your video finished transcoding.';
    } elseif ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'in_progress') {
        print 'Your video is still transcoding.';
    } else {
        print 'Your video encountered an error during transcoding.';
    }

    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=link');

    echo  $response['body']['link'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form201" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="my_field_add" value="" class="form-control" id="fi_pic">
    <input type="submit" value="save" name="saveUniv" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The page stops loading and there is no error message

After many attempts, I know that the location of the video is the problem

Comment: Have you checked the response from `devtool` > `Network` > `XHR`?

Comment: are you supposed to store the file on your server before calling the vimeo api?